# Place custom grid inside of div with susy

Tags: html, css, susy-compass

Suppose I have a grid with a container div, like such:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a2"></div>
    <div class="a3"></div>
    <div class="a4"></div>
</div>
```

and the following sass:

```
@import "susy";

$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutters: 1/4,
);

.a{
    background-color: blue;
    height: span(12);
    @include span(6);
}
```

Is it possible to then make the inside of `a` be its own 2x2 grid? I'd like to place `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` in each of the corners of `a` something like the following:

```
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4{
    height: span(1);
}
.a1, .a3{
    @include span(1);
}
.a2, .a4{
    @include span(last 1);
}
.a1{
    background-color: green;
}
.a2{
    background-color: orange;
}
.a3{
    background-color: red;
}
.a4{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Where I'd expect the top left corner to have `a1`, and go clock-wise through `a2`, `a3`, and `a4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `a` is currently spanning 6 columns on your main grid, so the simplest might be to make all your `a1`-`a4` elements span `3 of 6`:

```
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4 {
    @include span(3 of 6);
}
.a2, .a4{
    @include last;
}
```

But you can also declare any arbitrary context you want:

```
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4 {
    @include span(1 of 2);
}
.a2, .a4{
    @include last;
}
```

That's not guaranteed to line up with your global grid, but I don't know if you even want that. You can also look at the [`with-layout` wrapper](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#with-layout), if you want a new default grid for a larger block of code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric, I'll try this out and let you know how it goes.